# kill background while loop

Tags: bash, kill

i have a while loop to act as stopwatch and i want to implment it in script to count the time taken by command to run and i want to kill it after command finish

```
date1=`date +%s`; while true; do 
   echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
done &
```

i need to kill this loop inside the script

i tried

```
    1-jobs but it gives me no output
    2-kill $! but give me erro
```

but the loop is keep running

Comment: What about `date1=<date ..> ; command & wait ; echo -ne <date_diff>`?

Comment: its full script with multiple command  and i need to implement this part of loop to count time taken by each part of script in real time

Answer (score 0):

Use the `timeout` command provided by the `coreutils` package.

```
NAME

   timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
   timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
   timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
   Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

Comment: that's not what i want ..i need to get the script running time

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem but with a different context!

Make the while loop a function and get the PID of that right after you call it and kill it with that variable!

```
function loopToKill() { # while loop inside a function
   while true; do 
      echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
      sleep 1 # gotta have a sleep unless you want it to go crazy in the terminal
   done 
}

date1=`date +%s`
loopToKill &    # run in background
loopPID=$!      # get pid

# wait for whatever you needed

kill loopPID    # here's where it get's cool
```

Above you can kill it whenever you need to but it's all about waiting for what you need. This is the best work around for my situation, which was having a spinner for however long my process took. This was my own situation, but if your need is to keep the timer going for the length of the process then this is what you need.

Another cool thing would be using an input to kill it, this would need some more digging, I currently am working on it for fun, but don't know much about user inputs in bash aside from reading that they're risky. Best of luck, and thumbs me up if this helps!